# Routing of express-subdomain

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-subdomain

I'm using [express-subdomain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain).

The router that handles requests through a subdomain is the same as the router that handles requests without a subdomain.

I know that my 'app.js' setting is wrong.
How can I solve this problem? I want to know a good way. like this:

```
app.use(subdomain('banana', ('/about', bananaRouter);
```

and If this is an easy question, please forgive me. I couldn't find any of the same problems in my country. I'm sorry.

```js
// /app.js
const appleRouter = require('./routes/apple/index');
const appleAboutRouter = require('./routes/apple/about');
const applePriceRouter = require('./routes/apple/price');

const bananaRouter = require('./routes/banana/index');
const bananaAboutRouter = require('./routes/banana/about');
const bananaPriceRouter = require('./routes/banana/price');

const grapeRouter = require('./routes/grape/index');
const grapeAboutRouter = require('./routes/grape/about');
const grapePriceRouter = require('./routes/grape/price');

app.use(subdomain('banana', bananaRouter));
app.use(subdomain('grape', grapeRouter));

app.use('/', appleRouter);
app.use('/about', appleAboutRouter);
app.use('/price', applePriceRouter);

app.use('/', bananaRouter);
app.use('/about', bananaAboutRouter);
app.use('/price', bananaPriceRouter);

app.use('/', grapeRouter);
app.use('/about', grapeAboutRouter);
app.use('/price', grapePriceRouter);
```

```js
// /routes/apple/index
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('I am Apple');
});
module.exports = router;

// /routes/apple/about
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/view', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("Apples don't taste good.");
});
module.exports = router;

// /routes/apple/price
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/view', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("$ 1");
});
module.exports = router;
```

```js
// /routes/banana/index
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('I am Banana');
});
module.exports = router;

// /routes/banana/about
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/view', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("Bananas are delicious.");
});
module.exports = router;

// /routes/banana/price
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/view', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("$ 2");
});
module.exports = router;
```

```js
// /routes/grape/index
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('I am Grape');
});
module.exports = router;

// /routes/grape/about
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/view', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("Grapes are purple.");
});
module.exports = router;

// /routes/grape/price
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/view', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("$ 3");
});
module.exports = router;
```

Expected Behaviour 2:

```
// http://localhost.com:3000/
I am Apple
// http://localhost.com:3000/about/view
Apples don't taste good.
// http://localhost.com:3000/price/view
$ 1

// http://banana.localhost.com:3000/
I am Banana
// http://banana.localhost.com:3000/about/view
Apples don't taste good. ** not Bananas are delicious. **
// http://banana.localhost.com:3000/price/view
'$ 1' ** not '$ 2' **
```

Answer (score 0):

I created code sample which resolve you problem :D Firstly you need to add a couple lines to your /etc/hosts file. Example

```
127.0.0.1 banana.myapp.dev
127.0.0.1 myapp.dev
```

And after that try to run this script which I wrote for you:

```html
//connect express
var express = require('express');
var subdomain = require('express-subdomain');
var app = express();

app.use(express.json());

//set sub routing
app.sub_banana = express.Router();
app.use(subdomain('banana', app.sub_banana));

//top level routing
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('I am Apple')
});

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Apples don\'t taste good.')
});

//subdomain routing
app.sub_banana.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('I am Banana')
});

app.sub_banana.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Apples don\'t taste good.  ** not Bananas are delicious. **')
});

//start server
var http = require('http');

var port = 3000
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
```

Let me know if you need more information. I got my answer from this resource https://exceed-team.com/tech/express-subdomain